When to use residuals vs error propagation in curve fitting
I am trying to fit the data $t, y$ to a $t=0$ intercept point $y_0$ using the following model:
$$y = a \ln{(t+30)} + b \\ y_0 = a \ln{30} + b$$
I have two different methods of calculating the error on $y_0$, $\varepsilon_{y_0}$:

Error propagation: $\varepsilon_{y_0} = 
        \sqrt{
            {
                \left(
                    \frac{\partial y_0}{\partial a} \varepsilon_{a}
                \right)
            }^2
            +
            {
                \left(
                    \frac{\partial y_0}{\partial b} \varepsilon_{b}
                \right)
            }^2
            +
            2
            \left(
                \frac{
                    \partial y_0
                }{
                    \partial a
                }
            \right)
            \left(    
                \frac{
                    \partial y_0
                }{
                    \partial b
                }
            \right)
            \text{cov}(a, b)
        }
=
        \sqrt{
            {
                \left(
                    \ln{30}
                \right)
            }^2
            \mathbf{C}_{a,a}
            +
            \mathbf{C}_{b,b}
            +
            2
            \ln{(30)}
            \mathbf{C}_{a,b}
        }
$

where $\mathbf{C}$ is the covariance matrix.

Using the residuals of the fit: $
    \varepsilon_{y_0} 
    =
    \sqrt{
        \frac{
            1
        }{
            N-2
        }
        \sum_{i=1}^{N} 
        {
            \left(
                y_i - a \ln{(t_i + 30)} - b 
            \right)
        }^2
    }$

My question is simply, how do I decide which method to use? Are there rules for determining which approach is more appropriate given certain qualities of the data, and if so, what are those rules?

Neither is correct.  Please consult formulas for the standard errors of estimated coefficients in ordinary least squares regression.

I'm not following why neither is correct. The formulas for the standard errors of estimated coefficients in OLS end up being equivalent to (1), and why is using the residuals of the fit incorrect? Unless I've messed up transcribing the equation somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Your formula (2) estimates the sd of the errors, not the standard error of estimate of $y_0.$  The formula (1) is indeed correct--but does not require "error propagation," which is why I did not recognize it.  Moreover, it's silent concerning how $C$ is to be computed (which is what the standard OLS formulas will give you).
